# Parse Push has stopped

Tags: php, ios, swift, parse-platform

from the dashboard -> push, when we click "+ send a push", it displays the number of recipients > 0. when we select send to everyone, device type ios clients (all of our recipients are on ios) and send a message and when we go back to:

/push_notifications

the latest entries show 0 subscribes

There were no error messages displayed while sending. Just to reiterate, we selected send to everyone, not particular channel. No one received the push.

The older entries still show > 0 subscribers, the last few show 0.

Any idea what might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have all of your installations? Are you sending as message or json?

Comment: as json :( i want to do a silent notification to update my app in the background

Comment: Please can you show the Json that you are sending?

Comment: { "content-available": "1", "sound": "" } this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the format of your Json, quite often with Parse.com when you send json push notification that isn't in the correct format it will fail silently. Also Double check your certificates in parse.com. Ensure you have a .p12 with no password in the push notifications settings

Comment: Do you know that maybe ? Must the app run in the background in IOS to run the code which is in "func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification" ?

Comment: Unless you are using the fetchedCompletion handler:
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
      fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

If you are using this completion handler then it will launch your app into the background, if not then it will not work if the app is completely closed

Comment: So I using the using the fetchedCompletion so it will be run the code ? Without that my app is running ?

Comment: Correct :) Put that in and then code can be executed in there

Comment: Also when the user has closed the app ?

Comment: Yep thats right, mark the question as answered please :) This is diverging off topic from the original question, but I'm still happy to help out

Comment: Thank you, not a problem :) Happy developing!

Comment: Sorry i mean Also when the user has closed the app in the background process :)? Still i can run my code in the method ?

Comment: Yes thats correct. As long as you use this method notice the fetchCompletionHandler:

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
      fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Comment: i did that but when i close my app in the background he dont run any code